# How do I get the querystring using Golang's Fiber?

Tags: go, fibers

My code

```
   app.Get("/event/*", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {

                // GET THE ACCOUNT FROM THE PATH
                fmt.Println("PATH")
                fmt.Println(c.Path())
                fmt.Println("END PATH")
                fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c)
                fmt.Println("END PERCENT V")
                msg := fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", c.Params("*"))
                fmt.Println(msg)
                fmt.Println("END PARAMS *")
                fmt.Println(c.Body())
                fmt.Println("END BODY")
                fmt.Println(c)
                fmt.Println("END RAW")
```

I call this

```
curl 'localhost:3000/event/?a=b&b=c&d=e'
```

My output

```
PATH
/event/
END PATH
#0000000100000001 - 127.0.0.1:3000 <-> 127.0.0.1:46890 - GET http://localhost:3000/event/?a=b&b=c&d=e
END PERCENT V


END PARAMS *
[]
END BODY
#0000000100000001 - 127.0.0.1:3000 <-> 127.0.0.1:46890 - GET http://localhost:3000/event/?a=b&b=c&d=e
END RAW
```

What I want is
a=b&b=x&d=e as a string or as a json object.  However!  There is no fixed format to this string.  it could just as easily be blah=123&blah2=234.  or x=1&somekey=somevalue

All the docs i can find involve turning the querystring into a struct.  All this service needs to do is convert the query string to json and write it to disk.  If I drop the ?, I can use Params('*') to get it, but then the path is problematic, because I need the word "/event/" also.   And that value is also arbitrary.  This service just writes it to disk and return 200.

But I cannot figure out how to get the query string using golang's Fiber.   Is there a way?  If not, is there some other performant method of getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering as the *top* voted answer is ***wrong*** -- no longer working now, and the wiki link is outdated.

The newest doc is [here](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/ctx/#queries). Here is sample code:

```golang
// GET http://example.com/?name=alex&want_pizza=false&id=

app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    m := c.Queries()
    m["name"] // "alex"
    m["want_pizza"] // "false"
    m["id"] // ""
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 13):

You could simply use

```golang
app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) {
  queryValue := c.Query("param_key")
})
```

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/issues/193#issuecomment-591976894)

Comment: This is no longer working! Check the correct answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77313518/2125837

Answer (score 12):

`fiber` uses `fasthttp`.

- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2#Request
- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestCtx.URI

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func (c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        fmt.Println(string(c.Request().URI().QueryString()))
        return c.SendString("Hello, World!")
    })

    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":3000"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is `a=b&b=x&d=e` ***as a string***

Answering as the accepted one is outdated -- No need to dip into fasthttp any more, and can now simply use `c.OriginalURL()` to get back `"/search?q=something&and=more"`. See https://docs.gofiber.io/api/ctx/#originalurl

```golang
// GET http://example.com/search?q=something&and=more

app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
   c.OriginalURL() // "/search?q=something&and=more"

  // ...
})
```